# Docker exposed ports unreacheable

Tags: docker, port

I would like to run containers, with linkings between them. Each container should use another port. After I started all the containers, I cannot see exposed ports in `netstat --tcp` command output. I tried to use after that `--net=host` flag in `docker run` commands, but it causes error message above.

> Error response from daemon: Conflicting options: host type networking
>   can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.

How can I access to containers' ports in `myip:portnumber` format?

Comment: What does it mean "Each container should use another port?" Something like map port 80 of 1st container to host:81, 80 of second to host:82 etc? Do the containers need to be in the same network as host?

Comment: Linking will only expose ports between containers. To reach the ports from host, you need to do the standard port mapping like `docker run -p 80:80`

Comment: Also netstat will only show you open ports, that are "open" as a result of some application listening on them. Just because you expose a certain port in a container does not mean netstat will show it as "LISTENING" or the like.

Comment: I see, that ports are opened with `EXPOSE` in `Dockerfile`, but I cannot see port numbers in `docker ps -a` output.